# Can I pass two parameter in along with onkeypress event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I pass two parameters with the `onkeypress` event in JavaScript?

Here I passed `onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event,'+i+')"` I want validate it as number also use that number for future use.

```
for(var i = 0; i < (parsed_data.length - 1); i++) {
    que = que + '<tr>';
    que = que + '<td align="center" style="text-align: center;" ><input type="text" id="itemquentity[' + i + ']" value="' + parsed_data[i].itemquantity + '" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,' + i + ')" size="2" maxlength="2"></td>';
    que = que + '<td align="center" style="text-align: center;" ><label id="productitemprice[' + i + ']" for="productitemprice">' + parsed_data[i].productitemprice + '</label>$</td>';
    que = que + '<td align="center" style="text-align: center;" >' + parsed_data[i].productitemimgpath + '</td>'; 
    que = que + '</tr>';
    totalproductitemprice = totalproductitemprice + parseInt(parsed_data[i].productitemprice);
}
function isNumberKey(evt ,i ) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        alert('#productitemprice['+i+']');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when I do this it neither giving me alert message nor doing validation

Comment: Could you do a jsfiddle to show us your code in practice?

Comment: Please consider using one of many templating techniques in preference to "stringing" together HTML. e.g. place in a dummy `script` block with `type="text/template"` (so browsers ignore it), but you can then use string replace to insert values into placeholders (just a suggestion) :)

Comment: Check your browser's console log for any errors.

Comment: instead of sending i and then find an object you could send this object i.e. return isNumberKey(event,this). Then you can access that specific product item quantity object. To know more about your problem we need to get more details. Otherwise, use dev tools to find js error

Answer (score 0):

if you need numbers only allowed in text box try this

onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9 ]/g,'')";